# PHP program to check the connection of Mysql & Memcache

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

My project uses Zend Framework(1.x) and I want to create two methods/functions that can check the connections of Mysql and Memcache, and then I can save the check result in database.

Any function available to check he connection of Mysql & Memcache?

I guess a quick way to check Mysql connection, is just to use function like mysql->connect(), and then check the return value?

For Memcache, if there's no other checking function available, maybe just use something like:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', xxxxx);
```

Is my above method the most effective way? Don't know if there's any functions available or not.